# Concat object value with string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

I have an api response in react native  as

```
url_string = "https://example.com/"
//JSON Response

product_images: [
    {
        "url": "79/79B20211213054555pm1.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "url": "18/18c20211213054555pm2.jpeg"
    }
]
```

Now the thing is i want to append the url_string for each of the value as below with

```
//Expected Outcome - 

"new_product_images": [
    {
        "url": "https://example.com/79/79B20211213054555pm1.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://example.com/18/18c20211213054555pm2.jpeg"
    }
]
```

My attempt

```js
let product_images = [{
  "url": "79/79B20211213054555pm1.jpeg"
}, {
  "url": "99/79B20211213054555pm1.jpeg"
}];


Object.keys(product_images).forEach(function(key, i) {
  product_images[key] += "example/in";
});
console.log(product_images);
```

Comment: What did you try>?

Comment: In your console log you can see how you appended it to the end and also not used the url parameter. Just think a way to adding it to the start. Is a good exercise for learning to debug and analyze what is happening actually. I guess you should go for some JS tutorials before diving in like this.

Comment: I tried that @JorgeFuentesGonzález but it couldnt worked :(

Comment: @mplungjan P.S i am new to react

Comment: @DevenNazare This is basic JS actually. React has nothing to do. What he means is that you should know how to do that in JS before diving in react. Is just a tip, really.

Comment: @mplungjan your code doesn't work. You're taking advantage of the fact that objects are passed by reference, but the parameter is NOT passed by reference, so you're only mutating the parameter and not the real object. Should be `const baseUrl ="https://example.com/"; product_images = product_images.map(image => (image.url = baseUrl + image.url, image));`.

Comment: @code you are modifying the original. and if you do `const baseUrl ="https://example.com/", newImages = product_images.map(image => (image.url = baseUrl + image.url, image));` you fall in the same trap as I just did

Comment: @mplungjan the OP's attempt attempts to modify the original. Is that a problem?

Comment: `//Expected Outcome - "new_product_images":`

Comment: His "attempt" was a copy of a comment he wrote and later deleted - it is not 100% sure what OP wants, but he certainly needs to be aware of the issue you pointed out

Comment: @mplungjan okay. I don't see how I'm falling into the problem though, since my go there is truly to mutate the parameter and not the original.

Comment: But if OP took your code and thought he could just change the target variable name, he would be surprised

Comment: @mplungjan why?

Comment: As you saw, I fell for it, and someone with the same amount of rep as you aslo just fell for it and deleted their answer

Comment: AND [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71301238/295783)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and modify

If you do NOT copy, you may change the original array's URL object

```js
let product_images = [{
  "url": "79/79B20211213054555pm1.jpeg"
}, {
  "url": "99/79B20211213054555pm1.jpeg"
}];


const prefix = 'https://example.com';
const newImages = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product_images)); // deep copy
newImages.forEach(item => item.url = prefix + item.url); // modify
console.log(newImages)
console.log(product_images); // not modified
```

Shorter if in place modification

```js
let product_images = [{
  "url": "79/79B20211213054555pm1.jpeg"
}, {
  "url": "99/79B20211213054555pm1.jpeg"
}];


const prefix = 'https://example.com';
product_images.forEach(item => item.url = prefix + item.url); // modify
console.log(product_images); // now modified
```

***WATCH OUT, IT'S A TRAP***

This does not work as expected

```js
let product_images = [{
  "url": "79/79B20211213054555pm1.jpeg"
}, {
  "url": "99/79B20211213054555pm1.jpeg"
}];
const baseUrl = "https://example.com/",
  newImages = product_images
    .map(image => (image.url = baseUrl + image.url, image));

console.log(newImages)
console.log(product_images); // oops - modified too
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with a general function:

```js
const product_images = [
  {
    url: '79/79B20211213054555pm1.jpeg',
  },
  {
    url: '18/18c20211213054555pm2.jpeg',
  },
];

const concatString = (arr, key, concat) => {
  const newArr = arr.map((item) => {
    item[key] = concat + item[key];
    return item;
  });

  return newArr;
};

console.log(concatString(product_images, 'url', 'https://example.com/'));

console.log(product_images)
```

Comment: For a one-liner you can simplify it like so: `const concatString = (arr, key, concat) => arr.map((item) => ({ ...item, [key]: concat + item[key] }));`

Comment: And also YOU modify the original array since the url object is the same in both arrays

Comment: Seems a bit of over engineering